# what namespaces does http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation encompass

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have been looking for a while now.
How do I find which namespaces does http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation
encompass?

Comment: You're looking for everything that falls under the default WPF client / framework XAML namespace? That's a really broad question that would lead to a gigantic answer amigo.

Comment: why just the place where I can find it.

Comment: I have found a link which explains how to find it </br>
https://blog.pixelingene.com/2006/10/xmlnsdefinition-for-a-cool-namespace-mapping/.<br/>

Answer (score 0):

WPF use XmlnsDefinitionAttribute mapping CLR namespaces to XML namespaces in an Assembly.

Like below

```
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Documents"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shapes"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shell"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Navigation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Data"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media.Animation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Input"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media")
```

more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=netcore-3.1